# How to remove extension from multiple files in python

Tags: python, file

I have a folder which have more than 100 files. The folder contains.txt files. i want to remove ".txt" extension from all files. also tried os.path.splitext even os.remove it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `os.rename()`. The file name is just a string. You can remove the 4 last characters with:

```
src = 'path_to_txt.txt'
dst = src[:-4]
os.rename(src, dst)
```

Comment: okay and if folder have missing files like we have 100,101 and after that 104. how to deal this situation it shows error.

Comment: @AnmolHamid Well instead of assuming the folders content (and thus getting an error when the assumption is wrong and a file is missing); why don't you scan/list the folders content with either os.listdir() or os.scandir() ? With the second, the file name is retrieved by the .name attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stem` from the `pathlib` module.

```
import pathlib
file_name = pathlib.Path(‘textfile.txt‘)
file_name_wo_ext = file_name.stem
```

Comment: how to handle for multiple files..?

Comment: Create a list of files in the specified directory; loop for each file; apply desired modification

Comment: OP asked for multiple files. The answer should be suitable for the question.